# Gridview Command and Selected Row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to get the selected row data and transfer it to a label on the same page.  However I cannot get the Gridview.SelectedRow to work with my CommandName.  I have tried everything....

I get the error.  Object reference not set to an instance of an object. on Label2.Text

Here is my Code:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    // If multiple ButtonField column fields are used, use the
    // CommandName property to determine which button was clicked.
    if (e.CommandName == "Grab")
    {
        Label2.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text;
        Label3.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text;
        Label4.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[4].Text;
        Label5.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[5].Text;
    }
}
```

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#DEDFDE" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical" CssClass="td" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="574px" onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/edit.png" OnClick="ImageButton2_Click" />
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" CommandName="Select" ImageUrl="~/images/delete.png" onclientclick=" return confirm('Are you want to Delete this Vehicle?');" />
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton3" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/refre.png"  CommandName="Grab" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Year" HeaderText="Year" SortExpression="Year" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Make" HeaderText="Make" SortExpression="Make" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Model" HeaderText="Model" SortExpression="Model" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Submodel" HeaderText="Submodel" SortExpression="Submodel" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ISENABLED" HeaderText="ISENABLED" SortExpression="ISENABLED" />
    </Columns>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CE5D5A" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FBFBF2" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#848384" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#EAEAD3" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#575357" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this. Since you're trying to access the values in the `command` event and not in the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event you need to get hold of the row triggering the command event first.

```
if (e.CommandName == "Grab")
{
      GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)((ImageButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;
      if (row != null)
      {
          Label2.Text = row.Cells[2].Text;
          Label3.Text = row.Cells[3].Text;
          Label4.Text = row.Cells[4].Text;
          Label5.Text = row.Cells[5].Text;
      }
}
```

Comment: Ha...I was trying to get a button to show some text based on the selected row. This was always one post back behind, Using the OnSelectedIndexChanged solved the problem.